# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'students.xlsx'

Tags: python, flask

I create an excel sheet named students.xlsx in my home directory. I called it via POST method.But it shows an error: No such file or directory.

```
excelfile=request.files['file']
file=excelfile.filename

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
print(worksheet.cell(0, 0).value)
```

Comment: print the path and check

Answer (score 0):

If the snippet that you have provided is from your API, you have to know that the path to your XLSX file is no longer available for the web server.
As a fix for your approach, you can use the read() method provided for FileStorage objects ([FileStorage documentation](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage)) and provide file_contents parameter to open_workbook ([open_workbook documentation](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)).

As a conclusion, your code should should look something like this:

```
excelfile=request.files['file']
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=excelfile.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the student.xlsx file in static folder

Comment: or in a subfolder from the static folder